# C# Align Text Right in Console

Tags: c#, string, console

Is there a way for me to align text to the right side of my Console Application? I want to print a String with "[ok]" on the same line but on the right hand side. Like you see when booting a Linux Distro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest using curses as @Oded said.

If you really don't want to use any third party libraries, you can use `Console.BufferWidth` to get size of console and then `Console.Console.CursorLeft` to set column position.

```
Console.CursorLeft = Console.BufferWidth - 4;
Console.Write("[ok]");
```

The above prints [ok] at the end of the current line, leaving cursor at the first column, next line

Answer (score 18):

You could do something like this, if you're using Console.WriteLine...

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,20}", "Finished!", "[ok]");
```

Assuming your lines are 40 characters wide, the word "Finished" will be left-aligned in a 20 character field, and then the word "[ok]" will be right-aligned in another 20 character field. So you end up with something like

```
Finished!                            [ok]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) library - ncurses has a [c# binding](http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/).