# c# Console App Text Aligin when writing out list

Tags: c#, text, console, alignment

I am new to programming and am doing a console application.

At the moment the console app writes out what it is meant to but nothing is in alligment.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Item       Price       ID\n");

        foreach (var i in newItem)
        {

            string ite = i.Item;
            double pri = i.Price;
            int idd = i.ID;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}       {1}       {2}\n", ite, pri, idd);

        }
```

The formatting on this comes out really badly, any help would be appriciated, may not understand everything as I'm new to c#.

Comment: I have tried that but as some of the items in the list under 'item' are longer they still don't align nicely

Comment: Try having a look at this question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913563/c-sharp-align-text-right-in-console>

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t\t\t{1}\t\t\t{2}\n", ite, pri, idd));
```

instead of

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0}       {1}       {2}\n", ite, pri, idd);
```

This should space things out a bit. Depending on how wide your tab character is, and how many digits / characters are in your string you might need fewer or less than three tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like tabs to space the content out. Try

```
Console.WriteLine("Item\tPrice\tID\n");
...
Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n", ite, pri, idd);
```

Comment: It looks better, but some items in the list are longer, so is there a way of having the first WriteLine a 'header' and then everything alligns to that

Comment: Just make a Console.WriteLine wrapper or extension method of Console that wraps Console.WriteLine and puts in your desired formatting...

Comment: @JackBinnall That's kinda what programming is about. You either write your own method to measure how long the input strings are and return a nicely padded string, or just assume someone else has already done it, like in beruic's comment, and use their code. It'd be a nice exercise to write your own code to Writeline in a table style